# Gradle task list that can be parsed

Tags: gradle

I am looking for a way to retrieve the output of `gradle tasks` in a way that can be (easily) parsed.  Ideally in JSON for instance.

I feel that I am missing the obvious.  I was expecting to be able to do something like `gradle tasks --json`, or at least to find an equivalent somehow.  But I searched and found nothing.

Any idea?